# Problems giving focus to an iframe on smart tv

Tags: iframe, samsung-smart-tv

I am developing an application with sdk 3.1 - html/javascript/scenes.

i have an iframe with external content, but I can not move the tv's remote control focus to iframe (html).

is possible to do this or the API does not permit give the focus to an Iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked directly in the developer forum and corresta answer is that you can not.

I quote:

> **helpinghand2400@**
>
> Hi,
>
> Smart TV supports iFrames partially (We can only load the page ,
>   can't navigate it). So, you may be able to show the website in an
>   iFrame but you'll not be able to use most of the functionality

Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try manually set focus on that iframe? `myiframe.focus()` and than try to move with remote inside it?

Btw, as far as I experienced in previous applications almost in all cases you need to make your own focus handling.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use iframe on your Samsung Smart Tv App. It will be immediately rejected by Samsung testers. Their excuse is that iframes have serious problems on many devices.

There is no real solution for your question. Even Samsung is rejecting apps using iframe content. They have rejected one of my applications because of iframe.