# Browser callback in Samsung Tizen TV

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

We are developing a web app for Samsung tizen tv and stuck at payment. We are using third party payment apis which should open on webview and after transaction app should get a callback.

Please help us, how to get a callback from tizen browser to app.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung provides their own payment system for Tizen devices ([samsung checkout](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/samsung-checkout)) and
I'm not sure if using third-party libraries for in-app purchases is allowed by Seller office policies, at least without the approvement from Samsung. You should check it with your region's Samsung account manager.

Regarding the 'webview' in Tizen TV...

- What have you implement on your app? iFrames are supported partially on Tizen TVs, and Tizen webApis will not work on them ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640265/problems-giving-focus-to-an-iframe-on-smart-tv))
- When you said 'callback from Tizen Browser' I guess it is because you have tried to do an href to open your payment website 'inside' you app, but at this point then TV browser has been opened. Please note that any external link will be opened by the TV browser, and surely be [rejected by QA](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/how-to-open-external-url-as-main-page-of-app/201/309357?boardName=SDK&startId=00kGn~&startPage=15&curPage=17)

Comment: if we can't use iframe and webapis togather then what should we do then?